# No setter or field for string found on class W/ClassMapper

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a string birthdate defined in my user model class which is used to store the value of birthdate from date picker dialogue to shared Preference and firebase database. Here is my user model class

```
 public class User {
  public String name;
  public String email;
  public String userName;
  public String dateOfBirth;
  public com.example.webczar.chat_navigate.Structure.Message message;
  public Status status;
  public String avata;

 public User() {

    message = new com.example.webczar.chat_navigate.Structure.Message();
    status = new Status();
    status.isOnline = false;
    status.timestamp = 0;
    message.idReceiver = "0";
    message.idSender = "0";
    message.text = "";
    message.timestamp = 0;
}
```

And here is datepicker dialogue

```
 final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int myear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mmonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mdayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                 datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, 
       intyear, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

      String formatedDate = (dayOfMonth)+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+(year);
                                setPickedDate(formatedDate);
                            }
                        }, myear, mmonth, mdayOfMonth);
                    datePicker.show();
```

and in set picked date it is storing the picked date in database and preferences

```
   private void setPickedDate(String dob) { 
       userDB.child("birthDate").setValue(dob);
       user.dateOfBirth = dob;
       SharedPreferanceHelper preferanceHelper = 
       SharedPreferanceHelper.getInstance(context);
       preferanceHelper.saveUserInfo(user);
       Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"not set dob");
       setUserValues(user); }
```

even though it is storing the value in firebase JSON tree but it is not showing the value in text view like  other variables defined in user model class and throwing class mapper exception

Thank You.

Comment: Where is the code to add it to the textView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using this line of code:

```
userDB.child("birthDate").setValue(dob);
```

You are creating a new child name `birthDate` in your database. Even if you have this field declared in your model class, it's not initialized in the constructor and does not have also a public setter and getter. In order to solve this, initialize that value in the same way you to for the others. I recomand you change the model class like this:

```
public class User {public String name;
    private String email;
    private String userName;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private com.example.webczar.chat_navigate.Structure.Message message;
    private Status status;
    private String avata;

    public User() {
        //initialize fileds with desired values
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String userName, String dateOfBirth, com.example.webczar.chat_navigate.Structure.Message message, Status status, String avata) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
        this.avata = avata;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public com.example.webczar.chat_navigate.Structure.Message getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(com.example.webczar.chat_navigate.Structure.Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getAvata() {
        return avata;
    }

    public void setAvata(String avata) {
        this.avata = avata;
    }
}
```